# Load XML Views from an external file in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am new to UI5

Is there a way to load XML View code from an external file ?

Basically my XML code is growing & growing, its becoming difficult to manage. What I am trying to achieve is to put xml views in different files & call them from a parent xml view. IT seems there is no documentation about this on developer site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put reusable parts of your view definition into [fragments](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/36a5b130076e4b4aac2c27eebf324909.html).

Regards, matbtt

Comment: I was aware about fragments. But was'nt sure if the can be used in xml views. Thanks for assistance